# Print Out of Paper Cannot Fully Print

Tags: javascript, css

[image]

I have trouble to print the last column "Potensi", this text in this column cannot fully print, How can i fix the code? I use PHP. Thanks

Comment: PHP may generate the code but the issue is CSS/HTML. You need to reduce the size of your columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with PHP, it's a front-end problem. Also you may need to use [@media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) rule. so you can style your page in the printing mode.

For example you may reduce the font-size or reduce the padding of the page or anything else.

Comment: Thank you, I set my paper to A4 and its fit enough.